# Use MooseX meta attributes with Moops

Tags: perl, moose, moops

Is it possible to use MooseX meta attributes with Moops?

Consider this Moose sample code:

```perl
use v5.14;
use strict;
use warnings;

package TraitTest;
use Moose;
with 'MooseX::Getopt';
has opt1 => (
    traits => ['Getopt'],
    is => 'ro',
    isa => 'Bool',
    cmd_aliases => ['o']
);
1;
package main;
print TraitTest->new_with_options()->opt1 ? "yes\n" : "no\n";
```

I tried to transform this to Moops like so:

```perl
use v5.14;
use strict;
use warnings;

use Moops;
class TraitTest
with MooseX::Getopt
{

  has opt1 => (
#    metaclass => 'Getopt', # also not working
    traits => ['Getopt'],
    is => 'ro',
    isa => 'Bool',
    cmd_aliases => ['o']
  );
}
print TraitTest->new_with_options()->opt1 ? "yes\n" : "no\n";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moops classes are backed by Moo, not Moose by default. Thus MooseX extensions will not usually work.

However, it's possible to use Moose instead of Moo:

```
class TraitTest with MooseX::Getopt using Moose {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I read about `using Moose` in the documentation. I thought it might be possible to use the `Moo` "backend", as there is `MooX::late`. I'd really like to use `Moo` together with `MooseX::Getopt` - do you think it would be feasible to port it?

Comment: You could try [MooX::Options](https://metacpan.org/pod/MooX::Options) which is similar to (but not the same as) MooseX::Getopt, and works with Moo. (Until the most recent release of Moops, it didn't work with Moops. But it does now.)

Comment: Is there a way to set Moose as default instead of Moo?

Comment: For anyone wondering (because I had that question myself), in Zydeco you'd use `toolkit Moose (GetOpt);`